# could build a house

Tags: american-english

When I listen to pop music I always hear a sentence like "I showed them I could build a house". 
For example: 
They told me I was out there
Tried to knock me down
Took those sticks and stones
Showed 'em I could build a house

This is from Katy Perry. I have 2 questions in here. Does "stick and stones" and "I could build a house" have a literal meaning here? Or are they metaphorically written? and what that means?

Comment: "[Sticks and stones may break my bones...](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sticks-and-stones-may-break-my-bones-but-words-can-never-hurt-me)" The lyrics are metaphors. "Took those sticks and stones Showed 'em I could build a house."

Comment: It's an allusion to ***Sticks and stones may break my bones** [but names will never hurt me]*, with speaker adding the implication *I'll just take any weaponry you throw against me and use it to build myself an even stronger "fortress".* There's also an allusion to the "Three Little Piggies" (whose first two houses made of straw and sticks were torn down by the Big Bad Wolf, but their *third* house made of bricks/stone was tough enough to defeat the wolf).

Comment: "Could build a house" suggests that someone has the technical skills or financial resources to construct a house.  Hard to say for sure what the figurative meaning is, but the context suggests that the person can swing their arms like a carpenter wielding a hammer.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was what I exactly thought. Can I add to something.
She says: I'm the small town
One in seven billion
Why can't it be me?

What does "the small town" means here? and can you guess what is she trying to say with "why can't it be me?"

Comment: The basic concept here is *Using the enemy's strength against him* - which we're probably more familiar with these days from Far Eastern ***martial arts*** culture.

Comment: She is one person out of 7 billion [people on the planet]. She is "small town" – **unimportant**.

Comment: Does small town have any other meaning? or is it just a small-town. Just like when you say " I'm from small-town"

Comment: [Is the ideal of small-town America a myth?](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-18731576) Probably.

Comment: okay got it! Thank you again, sir.

Comment: "Showed 'em I could build a house
They tell me that I'm crazy
But I'll never let 'em change me
Till they cover me in daisies
Daisies, daisies"

    Do you think " cover me in daisies" has any meaning? Could it be " until they stop throwing sticks and stones and cover me in daisies" and daisies as in make peace with me?

Comment: More obviously, perhaps, covered by daisies growing *over my grave* - as in ***over my dead body!** [it ain't gonna happen]*.

Comment: I've never thought of that. That's a solid idea. Thanks again!